How do people in Australia know when chips refers to British crisps or American fries?
In Australia, chips refers to both British crisps (Americans call this chips as well) and American fries (British call this chips as well). This is never an issue for me as I never really buy British crisps, so most of the time when people say "chips" to me, it always refers to the American fries. However, it is still weird considering both are potato snacks, and while most of the time, chips as a side dish relates to American fries, there are restaurants that also serve the British crisps as a side. Aside from McDonalds, there are many restaurants that call British chips "fries". In many contexts, it can refer to both American fries and British crisps.

You've proposed more than one viable answer, I presume from experience: A) One is more common than the other; B) some places say "fries" when they need to disambiguate; C) they don't, everyone is a little confused. What are you hoping someone can tell you about this problem that you don't already know?

This is never an issue for me as I never really buy British crisps, so most of the time when people say "chips" to me, it always refers to the American fries. I don't see the logic of that. How does the fact that you don't eat crisps affect your understanding when someone else happens to mention 'chips'?

In Australia and New Zealand, a distinction is sometimes made between "hot chips" (fried potatoes) and "chips" or "potato chips". (Wikipedia)

It's not always possible to be certain but if in doubt, Australians ask. They're not shy.

Next time you're passing a chook stand, ask the bloke!

@Michael I have rarely heard people say "hot chips" or "potato chips". I have heard only "chips".

Well, that's what 'sometimes' means. As the answer below by @Astralbee says, context usually resolves apparent ambiguities.

Fair enough. Everyone's experiences vary. For instance, some user on Quora told me he hears "biscuit" and "queue" used much more than "cookie" and "line" in Sydney, but for me, it is the other way around. I actually havent heard a single person yet this year say "biscuit". I had heard "queue" a few times though. I heard "bikkie" said once to me, but that was only cause I ordered Kez's Bikkie Bites, and purposely kept calling it"Kez's Bites" to get the lady to say "bikkies".

The answer to your question is context. Context is how we differentiate all homonyms - how we know a baseball player is hitting the ball with a wooden bat, not a small flying mammal, for example.
In the USA, it's common to see 'Fish and Chips' on menus, and the context of pairing chips with fish is enough for most to know that these are British chips. Likewise, in the UK, if we see 'chips and dips' we know that means tortilla chips and dips such as salsa because the pairing is common.
It used to be generally true that the British say "chips" and Americans say "fries", but as the world has gotten smaller through communication and more people are aware of other cultures, that isn't necessarily the case. In the UK, it's common to see 'fries' (or 'French Fries') on menus, especially to describe the very thin-cut fries such as the ones sold in American fast-food chains like McDonald's. In fact, some restaurants in the UK now describe their chips as "chunky chips" on menus to differentiate them from the thinner 'fries'.
So, this will be no different in Australia. Context will dictate what is meant by 'chips'. As native speakers, we tend to anticipate if something might sound ambiguous and add context by making something more specific. Interestingly, when Americans say 'chips', this is short for 'potato chips', and while British chips are of course also made from potatoes, the longer name for these is 'chipped potatoes'. Subtly different, but it means that 'chips' just happens to be a shortening of two different things.
Questions like this tend to get multiple conflicting answers, with people from different places asserting what things are called. The fact is, there isn't even uniformity for names of things within a country - for example, in the UK, there are at least 16 different regional names for bread buns.

Weird thing is why America never writes "chips" for fries aside from fish and chips.
